# 4 same image with text overlay responsive

Tags: html, css

**Im using boostrap4.**
I need 4 boxes with  or image as background of col. Image always must be 100% height, and 100% width. Size of image = size of div
All images are 1080 width / 488 height

Its possibile to do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is set the images as background images and simply set the `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`. If you want to get fancy with it and have the boxes keep the aspect ratio of the image then you can play around with more advanced css tricks such as [the aspect ratio box](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/).

Comment: background-size: cover and background-size: contain not working